# DNS update for domain is not visible in my Ubuntu PC

Tags: networking, dns

4 days ago I changed my domain's name-servers. And after 2 days domain migrated to new hosting. But my computer(Ubuntu 12.04) is still opening old hosting when enter to my site. It is very strange. I checked with proxy tunnel sites, result: Everything is OK. I asked to friends to check, result: everything is OK. But only my laptop opens an old hosting, not new one.

- I tried with different browsers + did <kbd>F5</kbd>  and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>
- I cleared cache.
- I changed my network public DNS to Google Public DNS and restarted Ubuntu networking.

But still no result. Same old hosting opens. What else can I do?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What do you mean by "changing your domain's nameservers" and by "migrate"? I assume you didn't change the A records for your website two days before you went live at the new IP address.

Comment: Hey Jdhood. No you didn't get. My website migrated to new server. So its domain needed its nameservers(ns1 and ns2) to be changed. I changed. And usually such changes starts working worldwide after 24-48 hours. And it was so. After 48 hours everybody could open my website with new server. Except of me. Now everybody sees my site in new server. But my computer still opens it with old server. So problem is in my home computer with Ubuntu. Not in web server or in domain manager panel. I hope now you can get what i mean

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your website's domain names aren't listed in the /etc/hosts file.